# Less Battery consumption in between Thread,Service,Handler

Tags: android, performance, battery

I have to compare my location with the stored location in DB regularly after 30 seconds in my app. Please tell me which one is the best way to implement and less power consumption.

Comment: you could use broadcast receiver.

Comment: It doesn't matter ... as the main problem in battery draining would be GPS and CPU always on

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest `HandlerThread` or `IntentService` as it wont restrict your UI/Main thread.

This video should help you clear your doubts
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z5MZ0jL2BM

one not so efficient approach can be to use AlarmManager to schedule at callback very 30 secs ,on such callback perform ur task,they wont keep your resource awake when u r just waiting for next process step

Comment: make sure you handle the lifecycle correctly of whatever u use

Comment: @selvin , please correct me if i m mistaken , Handler thread would affect UI thread only when it is created or need to deliver something to the UI thread,other time it would be independent

Comment: @selvin , so do u agree with my answer or not ?

Comment: @Selvin ,totally agreed with ur view, in current scenerio would alarm manager or Scheduler be a good approach